# Quickbooks Online REST API Minor Version 7

Tags: rest, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to use the QBO Rest API to insert invoices into our system and want to use the *BillEmailCc* attribute of invoices. I've read on their site that these are only available for minor version 7. I've try setting the minor version in my queries but still I get errors saying this attribute is not valid. How can you access the minor version 7?

```
url: https:https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/193514338926917/query?query=SELECT%20BillEmail%20FROM%20Invoice%20WHERE%20CustomerRef%20%3D%20%2760%27&minorversion=7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging in the console, I deduced that the fields to set are as follows
`"AllowOnlinePayment":true,
"AllowOnlineCreditCardPayment":true,
"AllowOnlineACHPayment":true,`

Quickbooks support has said these attributes aren't supported, however.